# How can I increase the visibility of my bountied Android question?

Tags: support, bounties, bountied-tab

This is the second time I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994521/load-websites-in-offline-mode) about Android and put a bounty on it, but guess what despite the 150 rep bounty no one wants to answer it.

The Android section already has 51 featured questions and my question's been put at the last. So I guess the chances of it being answered within 6 days are quite slim.

Please make some changes in the bounty policy or whatever can be done to avoid this kind of trouble.

Comment: So you think that a change in bounty policy would generate more answers for you? How and why? Are you sure the problem is not in your *questions*? (I'm not saying that's the case - I know too little about Android to judge that. I'm just surprised about your assumption that changing the system will fix this.)

Comment: To be honest, the question is not all that great to begin with. It essentially states, this is my code, this is the tutorial I'm following, it doesn't work, please debug it. You might want to focus on the quality of your question before placing the blame on the system.

Comment: Bounties last seven seven days, yours hasn't even been up for more than one.  Patience.  That and as Bart said, that's really not a great question for SO.

Comment: Yes quite respectfully I do think thats the case. A week is not enough to generate qualified answers, especially for a question like mine. Normally I wouldn't put that much bounty on a question if I could figure it out within a few hours' searching and debugging.

Comment: Without specific suggestions for changes, or at least evidence that there is a pervasive problem, this is not a "discussion", "feature request", or "support" request, but simply a complaint, and therefore unconstructive as a Meta question.

Comment: A week is more than enough if your question's quality is sufficient and provides enough information to be able to solve the problem. No amount of bounty or time is going to save a poor question.

Comment: Keep in mind that "Featured" is like a FIFO queue. As your question approaches the 7 day mark, it gets moved up the list to the first page. The questions that are at the 1 hour mark are the first ones displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worth noting that [bountied questions rise in the featured list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) as they get closer to ending.

That doesn't mean anyone knows the answer to your question, or cares to answer it, but if someone does and is checking the Featured list, they're more and more likely to see it as the week progresses.